# Facebook API returns null when getting online_presence for non-friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a Facebook App that requests the user_online_presence permission. When user A logs in, they should be able to see if user B is currently online (assuming they have both accepted the permission).

This functionality works fine if user A is friends with user B, but it breaks if they are not friends (I have tested by friending and unfriending the same user).

Why is this breaking? Shouldn't the application be able to see if user A and B is online assuming they have the permissions, regardless of their friend status?

Thank you for your help